# Save method for Core Data calls "nil" the first time - Why?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am currently working on a core data survey application.  Right now, I am having trouble with my program when saving my core data entity after it is first created by the program.  I have an 'else' statement that is called the first time I save it.  The values are saved, but the application crashes.  I can then relaunch the application, and that NSManagedObject works normally.  The problem lies in my else statement, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
  if (rootController != nil) {
    if (team != nil) {
      [team setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"]; //UITextfield -> NSString
      [team setValue:teamNumber.text forKey:@"teamNumber"]; //UITextfield -> NSString
      [team setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:totalRank] forKey:@"totalRankValue"]; //Int -> NSNumber
      [team setValue:driveTrain.text forKey:@"driveTrain"]; //UITextfield -> NSString
      [team setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:autonomousRank] forKey:@"autonomousRankValue"]; //Int -> NSNumber
      [team setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:robotSpeedRank] forKey:@"robotSpeedRankValue"]; //Int -> NSNumber
      [team setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:minibotRank] forKey:@"minibotSpeedRankValue"]; //Int -> NSNumber
      [team setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:grabberRank] forKey:@"grabberRankValue"]; //Int -> NSNumber

      [rootController saveContext];

      NSLog(@"Save works - team is not nil");
      //Begin debug

      NSError* error;
      if(![[team managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
        if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
          for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
          }
        }
        NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);

      }

      //End debug
    } 
    else {
      [rootController insertTeamWithName:name.text 
                              teamNumber:teamNumber.text
                              driveTrain:driveTrain.text
                     autonomousRankValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:autonomousRank]
                        grabberRankValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:grabberRank]
                   minibotSpeedRankValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:minibotRank] 
                     robotSpeedRankValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:robotSpeedRank]
                          totalRankValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:totalRank]]; 

      NSLog(@"Team is nil");

      //Begin debug

      NSError* error;
      if(![[team managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
        if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
          for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
          }
        }
        else {
          NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
      }

      //End debug


    }
  }
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: I think it would be helpful to include the details of the crash too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I lack detailed information about the error I am going to guess that the problem is with this conditional:

```
if (team != nil) {
//...
}else{
//..
    if(![[team managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
         //...
}
```

You are getting the managedObjectContext from the `team` object even though that line of code is called only if `team==nil`. That means the call is always really:

```
if(![[nil managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
```

... which is never going to work.

Comment: When a new managedObjectContext team is first created, it is set as nil and calls the 'else'.  After the team is saved once, the program only uses the 'if' statement and should never call the 'else' statement.  The else statement works as long as I stick with NSString, but crashes the program when I use NSNumber.  As for detailed information about the error, do you have any suggestions for retrieving that information from the debugger? Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I realized that I never rephrased the question.  It should really be something more like "How do I properly save a new managedObjectContext".  I solved several of my problems during the process of writing the question XD